# Show that a surface of revolution locally admits a conformal parametrization

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, submanifold

Show that a surface of revolution locally admits a conformal parametrization, i.e.
$E = G$, and $F = 0$.
I can calculate that for a surface general surface of revolution i.e. $$f(u,v)=(r(v)\cos u,r(v)\sin u,h(v))$$
we have that
\begin{align*}
  f_u&=(-r(v)\sin u,r(u)\cos u,0)\\
  f_v&=(r^\prime(v)\cos u,r^\prime(v)\cos u,h^\prime(v))\\
  E&=f_u\cdot f_u=r^2(v)\\
  F&=f_u\cdot f_v=0\\
  G&=f_v\cdot f_v=r^{\prime2}(v)+h^{\prime2}(v)
 \end{align*}
then I don not know how to find the conformal parameterization, because I don't know how to make $$r^2(v)=r^{\prime2}(v)+h^{\prime2}(v).$$ Maybe I did not understand the meaning of "local" correctly? 
I tried to follows Ted's comment so that assume $$v=\phi(\bar{v})$$
then
\begin{align*}
\bar{E}&=r^{2}(\phi(\bar{v}))\\
\bar{G}&=r^{\prime 2}(\phi(\bar{v}))\phi^{\prime2}(\bar{v})+h^{\prime 2}(\phi(\bar{v}))\phi^{\prime2}(\bar{v})=\phi^{\prime2}(\bar{v})
\end{align*}
let $\bar{E}=\bar{G}$ so $$\phi^{\prime2}(\bar{v})=r^{2}(\phi(\bar{v})) \Rightarrow \phi^{\prime}(\bar{v})=r(\phi(\bar{v}))$$

Comment: So you are *given* such a parametrization, even with $r'^2 + h'^2 = 1$. How can you *reparametrize* to make $\tilde E = \tilde G$?

Comment: @TedShifrin, I think if $\bar{E}=\bar{G}$, I need $r^2(v)=1$, but why can we assume this exists?

Comment: No, of course not. $r$ and $h$ are given.

Comment: @TedShifrin, then I really do not know how, or is this question just incorrect?

Comment: Did you even read or work on my first comment?

Comment: OK, still way too general. If you think carefully, changing $v$ won't affect $E$. Can you make $v=\phi(u)$ to make $\tilde G = \tilde E = E$?

Comment: @TedShifrin, so we let $v=\phi(u)$ to be the inverse of $r^2$ and since $r^2$ is defined on an open internal of $\mathbb{R}$, so we can claim the existence?

Comment: No. Why are you still trying to make $\tilde E = 1$ when I've said explicitly that $E$ won't change? Moreover, what if $r$ is a constant function?

Comment: The latest edit essentially answers the question, giving a differential equation for the reparametrization $\phi$ for which existence of a solution is guaranteed.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang, sorry, I still have a question why the solution is guaranteed?

Comment: You can separate variables, integrate, and invert (i.e., establish existence of the inverse) to get $\bar{v}$ as a function of $v$.